# Directional collisions in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I have code for detecting collisions in PyGame, but how do you detect from which direction it collides?
My current code uses `obj.colliderect(wall)`, how could I modify this to suit my needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.get last position, get actual position on collision moment, find direction.

```
import math
x1,y1 = obj.pos
x2,y2 = obj.lastpos

x = x2 - x1
y = y2 - y1

angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y,x))
if angle < 0:  angle += 360
print(angle)
#now you have the angle from it was heading
```

2.if you have the obj direction angle:

```
angle = obj.get_angle()
angle += 180
while angle>360: angle += -360
print(angle)
#now you have the angle from it collides.
```